# ¿como hacer un desplazamiento en la misma pagina al selecionar una opcion de Radio Button?

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que cuando se selecione un radio button baje automaticamente la pantalla. 
Tengo este codigo HTML:

```
<label><input type="radio"  name="radio" value="1"  id="boton1"  class="ancla" data-ancla="scroll"  /></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="boton2"  class="ancla" data-ancla="scroll" /></label>
```

y este codigo JavaScript:

```
$('.ancla').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var strAncla = '#' + $(this).data('ancla');
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(strAncla).offset().top}, 1500);
});
```

Pero al darle click realiza lo que deseo pero no seleciona ningun radio button que utilizare despues para guardar en base de datos.

¿Como lo soluciono?
Gracias !

Comment: Solo tienes que setear la propiedad del otro radio button a checked después de haber bajado.

Comment: Y como hago eso?. Todavia tengo mucho que aprender y poco tiempo en la programacion. Muchas gracias.

Comment: sí, es cierto lo que dice @Diego Lopez. En la linea que hace el animate debe crear el callback `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(strAncla).offset().top}, 1500,function(){// Aqui debe setear la variable del radio button o el toggle});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede por que al hacer el `e.preventDefault();` estás anulando el comportamiento por defecto del `radio button`, entonces debes forzar que el atributo `checked` del elemento quede seleccionado usando la función `prop()` de **jQuery**, de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('.ancla').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        var elemento = $(this);
    
        var strAncla = '#' + $(this).data('ancla');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(strAncla).offset().top
        }, 1500, function(){ 
            $(elemento).prop("checked", true); 
        });
    });
```

```css
#scroll{
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label><input type="radio"  name="radio" value="1"  id="boton1"  class="ancla" data-ancla="scroll"  /></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="boton2"  class="ancla" data-ancla="scroll" /></label>

<div id="scroll"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias parcero!

Comment: Parcero ? sos de Colombia ? jajaja todo bien :D

Comment: Si, soy de colombia!. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto.

Debe haber una separación entre ambos para apreciar el desplazamiento.

Para probar el snippet activa la opción de `Página completa` que aparece a la derecha.

```js
$("#boton1").click(function() {

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#boton2").offset().top
  }, 1500);
  $("#boton2").prop("checked", true);

});
```

```css
.espacio {
  margin-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio"  name="radio" value="1"  id="boton1"  class="ancla" data-ancla="scroll"  /></label>
<div class="espacio"></div>
<label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="2" id="boton2"  class="ancla" data-ancla="scroll" /></label>
```