# ¿Cómo desplazar la página hasta la parte de arriba de la página al hacer clic en el botón?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

quería ver si me pueden orientar de como hacer lo siguiente,
quiero desplazarme hacia abajo en mi página cuando hago clic en el botón de especificación,

por ejemplo, después de hacer clic en 'btn', aparece una vista de cuadrícula un modal de loanding , pero el usuario tiene que desplazarse hacia arriba para ver la vista de cuadrícula, pero quiero que se mueva tan pronto como aparezca la vista de cuadrícula.

De antemano gracias

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlResultadosConsulta" Visible="false" runat="server" class="form-group  panel panel-primary margin-bottom-40">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Resultados de la búsqueda</div>
                    <div class="panel-body margin-bottom-50">
                        <div class="row table-outer">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="table-responsive" id="tblGuias">
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gdvResultadosConsulta" class="table table-striped table-responsive" BorderWidth="1" Font-Size="10px" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gdvResultadosConsulta_RowCommand" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="40" OnPageIndexChanging="gdvResultadosConsulta_OnPageIndexChanging">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lsrFst136_IdExpediente" HeaderText="ID DE EXPEDIENTE"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lsrFst136_NameTipoExpediente" HeaderText="TIPO DE EXPEDIENTE"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lsrFst136_GMaster" HeaderText="GUÍA MASTER"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lsrFst136_GHouse" HeaderText="GUÍA HOUSE"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lsrFst136_Registro" HeaderText="NUM REGISTRO"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lstrFst136_FechaEntrada" HeaderText="FECHA DE ENTRADA" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="lstrFst136_FechaGuardado" HeaderText="FECHA DE GUARDADO" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="false"></asp:BoundField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOCUMENTO" ItemStyle-CssClass="text-center">
    
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Button ID="btnConsultarDoc" runat="server" Text="Detalles" CommandName="btnConsultarDoc" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Style="border-color: dodgerblue; color: dodgerblue;" CommandArgument="<%#((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"></asp:Button>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
    
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="text-center" />
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
    
                                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="13" Font-Bold="true" Font-Underline="true" CssClass="GridPager" />
    
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Panel>
            </div>
```

Comment: Eso se hace en HTML con un ancla<a> y dinámicamente con JavaScript

Comment: <a href="#una-id">Ir al elemento con id="una-id" del propio documento</a>

Comment: <a id="una-id" title="Un título para el anclaje">Aquí viene</a>

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118371/como-hacer-un-desplazamiento-en-la-misma-pagina-al-selecionar-una-opcion-de-rad

Comment: Bueno yo ocupo un button por lo cual mi pregunta es respecto a si se puede eso, igual intente con el enlace que me mandas y varios ejemplos similares y dado que  es cpanel no me jalan estos. a menos que lo este colocando mal